# Cannot use type @TypeChecked and constructor

Tags: groovy

I have a class:

```
class MyClass{
   String myString1
   String myString2
}
```

I like to do:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(myString1: "1", myString2: "2")
```

However, I cannot do this in a method that is typeChecked. any ideas?

```
@TypeChecked
void myMethod() {
    ...
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass(myString1: "1", myString2: "2")
    ...
}
```

I get:

```
[Static type checking] - Cannot find matching method MyClass#<init>(java.util.Map
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
@TypeChecked
void myMethod() {
    //or def myClass
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass(myString1: "1", myString2: "2")
}
```

BTW which version of Groovy is being used?

Comment: Provide the full script. It works for me as expected in 2.2.1.